# PHP webservices using nusoap

Tags: php, xml, web-services, nusoap

when i am just trying to develope a simple webservice using Nusoap.when i am executing my server.php it executes and it shows an output of WSDL file and the method which i given.But ,when i try to execute my XML file it shows an error as document empty.i given that below.

This is the error:

```
  This page contains the following errors:

  error on line 1 at column 21: Extra content at the end of the document
  Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

And here is my XML file:

```
   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   Server: Microsoft-IIS/5.0
   Date: Thu, 24 Apr 2003 15:15:28 GMT
   X-Powered-By: PHP/4.0.6
   Server: NuSOAP Server v0.6.3
   Connection: Close
   Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
   Content-Length: 522

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
  <SOAP-ENV:Envelope
     SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
     xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
     xmlns:si="http://soapinterop.org/xsd">
     <SOAP-ENV:Body>
       <helloResponse>
           <return xsi:type="xsd:string">Hello, Scott</return>
        </helloResponse>
     </SOAP-ENV:Body>
   </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Can anyone please tell me what is the reason.

Comment: Have you specified a root element? That's mostly the problem.

Comment: no..i didn't specified the root element.can u please give me clear idea of what to do.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.w3schools.com/soap/soap_header.asp

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the namespace.
The namespace defines the Envelope as a SOAP Envelope.